# How to start script in VirtualBox Linux guest from Windows host?

Tags: windows, linux, virtualbox

I have a following build system:

- Windows host with a set of source files that need to be build
- Linux guest inside VirtualBox with build server

Now I mount filesystem through virtual box shared folders. Then I do the several steps to build system:

- Switch to VirtualBox
- Run build script
- Copy build result into shared folders

It is boring and time consuming to do that manually. How can I run shell script in VirtualBox guest from host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First create a **Windows** script (.cmd, .vbs) to run VirtualBox automatically (check [this documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp13963600))
2. Put the build script on your Linux machine to run at startup ([how-to for ubuntu](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3348-ubuntu-executing-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown))
3. Create a shell script that waits for the creation of your build results (should be easy to implement if you have the results in a unique form based on timestamp) and copies them into your shared folders